# JPA Foreign Key OneToMany

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have two entities, which are connected as a one to many relationship.

```
public class Book{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
  private List<Page> pages;
}

public class Page{
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
  public Book book;
}
```

So, a book can't be deleted if a page refers that book.
But how can I prevent pages beeing deleted as long as they reference a book ?

I'd like to have a foreign key constraint that prevents page objects to be deleted as long as they refer to any book.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for this using @PreRemove. This way it will prevent Pages from being deleted if they are linked to a book.

**BookRelationShipExist :** It's just an exception that you can create, you can also throw any other type of Exception

```
public class Page{
     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
     public Book book;

     @PreRemove
     private void preRemove() {
         if (book != null) {
               throw new BookRelationShipExist();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sure. It's not a foreign key constraint though, which is the thing you asked for in the question... It looks like you are fine with this check only working in JPA, but just to be sure: this does not prevent deletion when you do a plain SQL delete query.

Comment: Could you explain more please ^^

Comment: Thats a good solution anyway. Maybe I should create a FK manually for this. But this is definitly helpfull. Thank you very much!